# Manipulate a json object in redis using lua

Tags: json, lua, redis, eval

I am storing my objects in redis after serialising them to json and then converting json to strings. I want to be able to edit these objects using redis so I save on the network cost.

Instead of doing 3 steps :

1. Get object from redis
2. Edit the object in code and then serialise it to json
3. Set the object in redis

I want to simply do a set command with the redis key, json key and new value of the json key.

> {
>       "id" : "foo",
>       "name" : "far" }

I want to convert this user object to the following using a script:

> {
>       "id" : "foo",
>       "name" : "bar" }

I was playing around with `cjson.encode` and `cjson.decode` but cannot figure out a way to do this. Was missing how lua is able to access json objects.

**********************Answer*********************

I was able to write the script. I was missing out how to edit a json object in lua.

```
eval "local e = redis.call('exists', KEYS[1]) 
if (e == 1) then local obj = cjson.decode(redis.call('get', KEYS[1])) 
obj[ARGV[1]] = ARGV[2] 
redis.call('set', KEYS[1], cjson.encode(obj)) 
return table.getn(KEYS) 
else return -1 end" 
1 key n rani
```

Comment: If you're open to it, there is a redis module (available in redis 4.0, which is in RC stage right now), that does exactly that with special JSON manipulation commands. Check it out: https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/rejson

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer Thanks. Will check this out.

Comment: it's EXACTLY what you need, will work far better and simpler than Lua, and it's super fast as it's written in highly optimized C. And while redis 4.0 is still RC, I've been using it for the past 6 months and it's very stable, so don't worry about that either.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I am not sure if we are ready to shift to redis 4.0. In fact we recently moved from Amazon Elasticache to own servers with redis 3.2.8. Will definitely keep this in mind for the upcoming cases. But for now, I have to rely on lua only.

Comment: Fair enough. Stable release of it is a matter of a couple of weeks BTW.

Comment: For the OP's reference - ReJSON has a couple of Lua scripts that do that (without ReJSON): https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/rejson/blob/master/benchmarks/lua/json-set-path.lua

Comment: @ItamarHaber Thanks a lot for sharing. This was very helpful. However I am stuck at one more place. I want to be able to read "true" from the console arguments and convert it to a lua variable of boolean type. I am looking for a toboolean() method which works like the tonumber() method. There is a mention of lua_toboolean() method in the manual here https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html but that is not working in redis eval. Right now, I am sending arguments - (key, value, datatype) and if the datatype is boolean, sending 0/1 values and setting accordingly. Any cleaner ideas?

Comment: lua_toboolean belongs to the C API that Lua provides, so trying to EVAL it fails naturally. You'll have to do your own conversion, there's nothing "cleaner".